# How to change data in a listview using arrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a string list outputting certain data throw a listview using arrayAdapter, what I want to know is how to periodically change the data while the app is running, say for example how to add a count down timer to my listView

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows you how to add a countdown [timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) to a `listview` :

**Step 1**: setup your `listview`:

```
//data
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("Item 1");
values.add("Item 2");
values.add("Item 3");


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

ListView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**step 2**: create a countdown `timer`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something in here
    }
};
```

**step 3**: start your `timer`:

You have different option in here,

You can execute your code after the specified delay:

```
//here your code will be execute after 5000 ms (5s)
timer.schedule(task, 5000);
```

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution :

```
//execute task every 5000 ms
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 5000);
```

**step 4**: connect the timer to our `listview` by adding our code in the `run` method:

```
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.add("New Item");
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Here we have to wrap our code inside `recyclerView.post()` because we are in a different `thread` and we can't touch the android `view` from it, we have to so `post` our `task` to the main `thread`

**Summary**: Here's what you might need to use:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //data
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("Item 1");
        values.add("Item 2");
        values.add("Item 3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        ListView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.add("New Item");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        
        //here your code will be execute afer 5000 ms (5s)
        timer.schedule(task, 5000);
    }
}
```